# UICollectionView, UICollectionCell and IBOutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two separate xib. One hold main screen as child of `UIView` and also `UICollectionView`. Second xib contains `UICollectionCell`. If I just run my code as it is, it is working. (First xib with `UIView` is used in storyboard, its places in `UIViewController`).

I have this in `- (void) awakeFromNib`

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ViewCellNIB" bundle:nil];
[self.todayScroll registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TodayCellID"];
```

Now, I want to add some `IBOutlet` connections into **ViewCellNIB**. If I do this, my code crash in runtime with this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0xb068b10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key temporaryLabel.'
```

I have this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *temporaryLabel;
```

connected to `UILabel` on `UICollectionViewCell`

How can I repair this ?

Comment: did you declare the cell in your xib a subclass of your custom cell class?

Comment: In header I have: @interface ViewCellNIB : UICollectionViewCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I have found solution. My mistake. I have incorrectly connect IBOutlet in Designer. I have to connect outlets via main UICollectionViewCell and not directly by dragging connection from element to code.